# TFS Creating Build script for releases

Tags: powershell, tfs

I want to be able to set up a semi automatic Build script to check out a specific commit from our TFS server to a non generic folder to then cause the code to be built and packaged to enable a release.

I understand how to use the command line, and can script it fine, but its how to create a temporary workspace that will not interfere with the existing workspace on the machine to check the code out into.

I will have to research how to build the solution as well from the commandline but that may not be as hard as this...

Comment: What build system are you using now?

Comment: none. that's the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command line tool `tf.exe` to create a new workspace e.g.:

```
tf workspace /new workspace_name`;username /collection:http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

You can get work folder mappings by using a template when creating the new workspace.  See the `/template` parameter on `tf workspace`.  Or you can use the `tf workfold /map` command to create work folder mappings for the new workspace.  When you're done, use `tf workspace /delete` to delete the workspace.